# Word Prediction like Android "keyboard"

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, auto-completion

Is there a way to get word prediction like on android?

Like on this screenshot:

[image]

This would improve the speed of typing on Ubuntu a lot.

I need it here:

- thunderbird
- Browser textarea
- gedit

Required feature:

- Needs to work online and offline (without internet connection)

**Update**

I gave a bounty for this question and still no answer. I guess the desktop is dying. I guess sooner or later I will use android instead of ubuntu.

Comment: Not system wide, but it's something! https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/subject-write-emails-faster-smart-compose-gmail/

Comment: @j-money I updated the question:  Needs to work online and offline (without internet connection)

Comment: j-money wrote "**Not system wide**..."

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Onboard/SpecWordPrediction

Comment: One more requirement could be the need to auto-correct auto-complete gaffes ;)

Comment: You probably will need to find separate solutions for each application. If you install *gedit-plugins* it'll give you *gedit-plugin-word-completion*. I know that LibreOffice Writer also has something similar.

Comment: Do you use on screen keyboard?

Comment: @Kulfy No, I don't use a on screen keyboard.

Comment: This still has no valid answer. I see nothing in the answer marked as definitive that is close to the phone-tablet option (that exists also on iphone/ipad, not just Android phones). A more useful reference would be that to Windows 10, as Ubuntu would be expected to match that. As per a comment under [Text editor with Android-like suggestion strip for desktop](https://superuser.com/q/1625502/1039759) linking to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/enable-text-suggestions-for-inclusive-classrooms-8ca3ea32-66b1-4d9d-abf1-1d0ead34f2a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE).

Comment: @Alexey please post it as answer, so I can up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider [`Ibus-typing-booster`](https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/). From the project home page introduction:

> Ibus-typing-booster is a completion input method to speedup typing.
>
> The project was started in 2010 for Fedora 15. The original purpose was to make typing of Indic languages easier and faster by providing completion and spell checking suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking in the wrong place. If what you want is a keyboard that can replace the android keyboard (with word prediction), there are plenty:

[Florence](https://sourceforge.net/projects/florence/#screenshots) & [xvkbd](http://t-sato.in.coocan.jp/xvkbd/)

Florence is especially nice if you use GNOME.

Other options are available as well.

Unfortunately, what you REALLY are looking for is word prediction from your already existing dumb keyboard. See, on android and other screens, you input using virtual keyboards. On Desktops/Laptops, you have ACTUAL keyboards, which are different, and functionality can't be added to them once produced.

Virtual keyboards can be replaced, upgraded and functionality added. So, both the systems have that.

Lastly, a hybrid does exists, [TextSuggest](https://gitlab.com/bharadwaj-raju/TextSuggest) , a program that shows completions for the word selected or (optionally) currently being typed (from its description).
You have to hit a global shortcut for it showup, much like tab-completion on terminals.

[image]
[image: Florence with pretty decorations]

Comment: There would be no big deal in typing the real keyboard and having the "suggestions strip" on the screen, Windows already has that. The above is not really the answer.

Comment: I am not looking for a virtual keyboard. I think this is the right answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1382808/42348

Answer (score 2):

You should try [pyprompter](https://reposcope.com/package/pyprompter):

> pyprompter displays predictions in a contextual pop-up box as each letter is typed. Predictions can be easily selected and inserted in the document.

It is based on [Presage](https://presage.sourceforge.io/), which is "an intelligent predictive text entry system."

It should work online and offline.

Comment: I read "pyprompter - intelligent predictive wxPython text editor". I guess it is nice if you develop an own application. I was looking for something which works with existing applications (thundebird, firefox, chrome, gedit, ...)